# WSL, can not access node http server throught hostname mapped in hosts file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was using WSL2 to run a node server, when I only pass port to `listen`,

```
const https = require('https');
https.createServer(***).listen(3001);
```

the `lsof -i` display something like this

```
node    13347 0t0  TCP *:3001 (LISTEN)
```

I can not access this server through the hostname mapped in the hostfile(/etc/hosts) somehow, Why?

```
127.0.0.1 local.test.com
```

when I change the node app code to this:

```
const https = require('https');
https.createServer(***).listen(3001, '127.0.0.1');
```

`lsof -i` shows:

```
node 0t0  TCP localhost:3001 (LISTEN)
node 0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
```

for now I can access the server through the hostname I mapped in the host file

But if I changed the node app code to:

```
const https = require('https');
https.createServer(***).listen(3001, 'localhost');
```

the `lsof -i` will show:

```
node  0t0  TCP kubernetes.docker.internal:3001 (LISTEN)
node  0t0  TCP kubernetes.docker.internal:3000 (LISTEN)
```

why there had an address named kubernetes.docker.internal?
I even not runing docker(I installed docker anyway).

Comment: Some more details are needed -- *"I can not access this server"*  What is the result?  From what application are you trying to access it?  Are you trying to access it from within WSL or from within the Windows host?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I using chrome installed on windows to vistit local.test.com. it shows connection refused

Comment: [The Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlistenport-host-backlog-callback) states: *"If `host` is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (`::`) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (`0.0.0.0`) otherwise."* Despite this, I also had to have an explicit `host` in my `server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0")` to make my `hosts` file work. I'm not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your Windows host file content, you'll find the Docker Desktop hostname configuration:

Example of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
<host-ip> host.docker.internal
<host-ip> gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

You should do the same, add the hostname (`127.0.0.1 local.test.com`) configuration on the Windows host file, not in WSL...